# Showing just the html content of a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a react component called `<Currency />` that takes a currency and value.

So if I did `<Currency value={10} currency={"USD"}/>` it would return `<span>$10.00</span>`

I am then using this in a separate component.

```
    if (amount < limit){

        let value  = <Currency value={this.state.depositLimit} currency={this.state.currency} />;

        return this.setState({
            error:`Minimum limit is ${value}`
        });

    }
```

This renders `Minimum deposit is [object Object]` on the screen.
Does anyone know how I can just show the content of the component i.e. `$10.00`

Comment: Why don't you directly use `this.state.depositLimit` and `this.state.currency` ?

Comment: @FiriceNguyen because the currecny is `USD` and not `$`, whereas my `Currency` component converts this.

Comment: React elements can be used only in `render()` method of statefull components and in `return` statement of stateless components. You're using the React element in the wrong way, could you add full source code of your component? That would be easier to make advice.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using JSX outside of a render function. Additionally, avoid putting too much information in your component state. I suggest storing the nature of the error, not necessarily the error message itself.

```
this.setState({
  minDepositError: true,
});
```

Instead, use the render function to spell out the error message.

```
if (this.state.minDepositError) {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Minimum limit is </span>
      <Currency
        currency={this.state.currency}
        value={this.state.depositLimit}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Good shout actually, I will take this approach.

Answer (score 0):

ReactServer [renderToString](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) is what you want.

`ReactDOMServer.renderToString(value)`

Comment: `Render a React element to its initial HTML. This should only be used on the server. React will return an HTML string.` **This is all client side**